# Year wise aggregation on the given condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below. which is a sales data of two health care product starting from December 2016 to November 2018.

```
 product     price      sale_date       discount
   A         50         2016-12-01      5
   A         50         2017-01-03      4
   B         200        2016-12-24      10
   A         50         2017-01-18      3
   B         200        2017-01-28      15
   A         50         2017-01-18      6
   B         200        2017-01-28      20
   A         50         2017-04-18      6
   B         200        2017-12-08      25
   A         50         2017-11-18      6
   B         200        2017-08-21      20
   B         200        2017-12-28      30
   A         50         2018-03-18      10
   B         300        2018-06-08      45
   B         300        2018-09-20      50
   A         50         2018-11-18      8
   B         300        2018-11-28      35
```

From the above I would like to prepare below data frame

Expected Output:

```
product    year     number_of_months     total_price total_discount number_of_sales
A          2016     1                    50            5            1
B          2016     1                    200           10           1
A          2017     12                   250           25           5
B          2017     12                   1000          110          5  
A          2018     11                   100           18           2
B          2018     11                   900           130          3
```

Note: Please note that the data starts from Dec 2016 to Nov 2018.
So number of months in 2016 is 1, in 2017 we have full data so 12 months and 2018 we have 11 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` by years and `product` and then create new column for counts by months by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 =(df.groupby(['product',df['sale_date'].dt.year], sort=False).sum().add_prefix('total_')
        .reset_index())

df1.insert(2,'number_of_months', df1['sale_date'].map({2016:1, 2017:12, 2018:11}))
print (df1)

  product  sale_date  number_of_months  total_price  total_discount
0       A       2016                 1           50               5
1       A       2017                12          250              25
2       B       2016                 1          200              10
3       B       2017                12         1000             110
4       A       2018                11          100              18
5       B       2018                11          900             130
```

If want dynamic dictionary by minumal and maximal datetimes use:

```
s = pd.date_range(df['sale_date'].min(), df['sale_date'].max(), freq='MS')

d = s.year.value_counts().to_dict()
print (d)
{2017: 12, 2018: 11, 2016: 1}

df1 = (df.groupby(['product',df['sale_date'].dt.year], sort=False).sum().add_prefix('total_')
        .reset_index())

df1.insert(2,'number_of_months', df1['sale_date'].map(d))
print (df1)
  product  sale_date  number_of_months  total_price  total_discount
0       A       2016                 1           50               5
1       A       2017                12          250              25
2       B       2016                 1          200              10
3       B       2017                12         1000             110
4       A       2018                11          100              18
5       B       2018                11          900             130
```

For ploting is used [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df2 = (df1.set_index(['sale_date','product'])[['total_price','total_discount']]
         .unstack(fill_value=0))
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df2)
          total_price_A  total_price_B  total_discount_A  total_discount_B
sale_date                                                                  
2016                  50            200                 5                10
2017                 250           1000                25               110
2018                 100            900                18               130

df2.plot()
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['product',df['sale_date'].dt.year], sort=False)
        .agg( total_price=('price','sum'),
             total_discount=('discount','sum'),
             number_of_sales=('discount','size'))
        .reset_index())

df1.insert(2,'number_of_months', df1['sale_date'].map({2016:1, 2017:12, 2018:11}))
print (df1)
  product  sale_date  number_of_months  total_price  total_discount  \
0       A       2016               NaN           50               5   
1       A       2017               NaN          250              25   
2       B       2016               NaN          200              10   
3       B       2017               NaN         1000             110   
4       A       2018               NaN          100              18   
5       B       2018               NaN          900             130   

   number_of_sales  
0                1  
1                5  
2                1  
3                5  
4                2  
5                3
```

Comment: is it possible to plot that in line plot in python using plotly.
x axis - year
y axis - total_price
y axis -  total_discount
For A and B seperately

Comment: @Danish One question - numner of years is count form first and last value like second solution or by years like first solution?

Comment: pls help me in plotting that using pyton.

Comment: @Danish - So there are 4 lines in plot?

Comment: Yes. I would like to have two line plot for Product A in one. And similarly for Product B

Comment: Thank you so much.. In this I would like to add one column called number of sales. Should I add new question?

Comment: @Danish - Be free edit this question with expected output DataFrame for plot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216379/discussion-between-danish-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Danish - Answer was edited with new aggregation function for new column

Comment: number of months are NaN

Comment: @Danish - My typo `df['sale_date']` instead `df1['sale_date']`, answer was edited.

Comment: added new question pls look into this during your free time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63323668/append-a-column-from-one-df-to-another-based-on-the-date-column-on-both-dfs-pa