# Append a column from one df to another based on the date column on both dfs - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dfs as shown below.

df1:

```
Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-02             23              
2020-02-03             14           
2020-02-04             23
2020-02-05             23  
2020-02-06             23          
2020-02-07             30            
2020-02-08             29            
2020-02-09             100
2020-02-10             38
2020-02-11             38               
2020-02-12             38                    
2020-02-13             70           
2020-02-14             70 
2020-02-15             38               
2020-02-16             38                    
2020-02-17             70           
2020-02-18             70 
2020-02-19             38               
2020-02-20             38                    
2020-02-21             70           
2020-02-22             70 
2020-02-23             38               
2020-02-24             38                    
2020-02-25             70           
2020-02-26             70 
2020-02-27             70
```

df2:

```
From                to                   plan          score
2020-02-03          2020-02-05           start         20
2020-02-07          2020-02-08           foundation    25
2020-02-10          2020-02-12           learn         10
2020-02-14          2020-02-16           practice      20
2020-02-15          2020-02-21           exam          30
2020-02-20          2020-02-23           test          10
```

From the above I would like to append the `plan` column to df1 based on the `From` and `to` date value in df2 and `Date` value in df1.

Expected output:

output_df

```
Date                t_factor        plan
2020-02-01             5            NaN
2020-02-02             23           NaN   
2020-02-03             14           start          
2020-02-04             23           start
2020-02-05             23           start  
2020-02-06             23           NaN
2020-02-07             30           foundation               
2020-02-08             29           foundation        
2020-02-09             100          NaN
2020-02-10             38           learn
2020-02-11             38           learn              
2020-02-12             38           learn                   
2020-02-13             70           NaN
2020-02-14             70           practice
2020-02-15             38           NaN              
2020-02-16             38           NaN                    
2020-02-17             70           exam      
2020-02-18             70           exam
2020-02-19             38           exam   
2020-02-20             38           NaN                 
2020-02-21             70           NaN         
2020-02-22             70           test
2020-02-23             38           test             
2020-02-24             38           NaN        
2020-02-25             70           NaN
2020-02-26             70           NaN
2020-02-27             70           NaN
```

Note:

If there is any overlapping date, then keep plan as NaN for that date.

Example:

`2020-02-14` to `2020-02-16` `plan` is `practice`.

And `2020-02-15` to `2020-02-21` `plan` is `exam`.

So there is overlap is on `2020-02-15` and `2020-02-16`.

Hence `plan` should be `NaN` for that date range.

I would like to implement function shown below.

```
def (df1, df2)
    return output_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:** (This solution if `From` and `to` dates in dataframe `df2` overlaps and we need to choose the values from column `plan` with respect to earliest date possible)

```
d1 = df1.sort_values('Date')
d2 = df2.sort_values('From')


df = pd.merge_asof(d1, d2[['From', 'plan']], left_on='Date', right_on='From')
df = pd.merge_asof(df, d2[['to', 'plan']],   left_on='Date', right_on='to',
                   direction='forward', suffixes=['', '_r']).drop(['From', 'to'], 1)

df['plan'] = df['plan'].mask(df['plan'].ne(df.pop('plan_r')))
```

**Details:**

Use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to perform a **asof merge** on the dataframes `d1` and `d2` on corresponding columns `Date` and `From` with default `direction='backward'` to create a new merged dataframe `df`, again use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to **asof merge** the dataframes `df` and `d2` on corresponding columns `Date` and `to` with `direction='forward'`.

```
print(df)

         Date  t_factor        plan      plan_r
0  2020-02-01         5         NaN       start
1  2020-02-02        23         NaN       start
2  2020-02-03        14       start       start
3  2020-02-04        23       start       start
4  2020-02-05        23       start       start
5  2020-02-06        23       start  foundation
6  2020-02-07        30  foundation  foundation
7  2020-02-08        29  foundation  foundation
8  2020-02-09       100  foundation       learn
9  2020-02-10        38       learn       learn
10 2020-02-11        38       learn       learn
11 2020-02-12        38       learn       learn
12 2020-02-13        70       learn    practice
13 2020-02-14        70    practice    practice
14 2020-02-15        38        exam    practice
15 2020-02-16        38        exam    practice
16 2020-02-17        70        exam        exam
17 2020-02-18        70        exam        exam
18 2020-02-19        38        exam        exam
19 2020-02-20        38        test        exam
20 2020-02-21        70        test        exam
21 2020-02-22        70        test        test
22 2020-02-23        38        test        test
23 2020-02-24        38        test         NaN
24 2020-02-25        70        test         NaN
25 2020-02-26        70        test         NaN
26 2020-02-27        70        test         NaN
```

Use [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) + [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to mask the values in column `plan` where `plan` is not equal to `plan_r`.

```
print(df)

         Date  t_factor        plan
0  2020-02-01         5         NaN
1  2020-02-02        23         NaN
2  2020-02-03        14       start
3  2020-02-04        23       start
4  2020-02-05        23       start
5  2020-02-06        23         NaN
6  2020-02-07        30  foundation
7  2020-02-08        29  foundation
8  2020-02-09       100         NaN
9  2020-02-10        38       learn
10 2020-02-11        38       learn
11 2020-02-12        38       learn
12 2020-02-13        70         NaN
13 2020-02-14        70    practice
14 2020-02-15        38         NaN
15 2020-02-16        38         NaN
16 2020-02-17        70        exam
17 2020-02-18        70        exam
18 2020-02-19        38        exam
19 2020-02-20        38         NaN
20 2020-02-21        70         NaN
21 2020-02-22        70        test
22 2020-02-23        38        test
23 2020-02-24        38         NaN
24 2020-02-25        70         NaN
25 2020-02-26        70         NaN
26 2020-02-27        70         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) convert the date like columns to pandas datetime series:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2[['From', 'to']] = df2[['From', 'to']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Create a [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) from the columns `From` and `to` of `df2`, then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on the column `Date` of `df1` to map it to column `plan` from `df2` (after setting the `idx`):

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['From'], df2['to'], closed='both')
df1['plan'] = df1['Date'].map(df2.set_index(idx)['plan'])
```

Result:

```
         Date  t_factor        plan
0  2020-02-01         5         NaN
1  2020-02-02        23         NaN
2  2020-02-03        14       start
3  2020-02-04        23       start
4  2020-02-05        23       start
5  2020-02-06        23         NaN
6  2020-02-07        30  foundation
7  2020-02-08        29  foundation
8  2020-02-09       100         NaN
9  2020-02-10        38       learn
10 2020-02-11        38       learn
11 2020-02-12        38       learn
12 2020-02-13        70         NaN
13 2020-02-14        70    practice
14 2020-02-15        38    practice
15 2020-02-16        38    practice
16 2020-02-17        70        exam
17 2020-02-18        70        exam
18 2020-02-19        38         NaN
19 2020-02-20        38        test
20 2020-02-21        70        test
21 2020-02-22        70        test
22 2020-02-23        38        test
23 2020-02-24        38         NaN
24 2020-02-25        70         NaN
25 2020-02-26        70         NaN
26 2020-02-27        70         NaN
```